# The ul element does not appear after clicking the checkbox

Tags: html, css, navigation, nav

My responsive page has a nav menu on top. But for mobile resolution I created a button that opens up a ul of that nav bar upon clicking. It should work given the code, but it does not appear. I have tried my best to make it work but nothing seems to work. I still do not use javascript and I don't want to for the time being. So I wish to make it work using only CSS.

I tried this method to transform a div. Which absolutely worked fine.

```
#check:checked ~ .uno {
```

But if I use this same method to show the ul (as below) upon clicking the invisible checkbox, it doesn't work.

`#check:checked ~ #nav-list{`(to make it display block from display none)

Here's the code of the whole thing.

```css
nav {
  background-color : #0e1317;
  width            : 100%;
  position         : absolute;
  z-index          : 2;
  height           : 300px;
  }
nav .navbar {
  display          : flex;
  justify-content  : space-between;
  width            : 95%;
  margin           : auto;
  background-color : #0e1317;
  padding          : 20px 0;
  }
#nav-list {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  }
.uno, .duo {
  position         : absolute;
  height           : 2px;
  right            : 15px;
  top              : 35px;
  width            : 25px;
  background-color : aliceblue;
  transition       : all 1s;
  }
.duo {
  top : 45px;
  }
#check:checked~.duo {
  rotate    : -45deg;
  transform : translate(5px, -5px);
  }
#check:checked~.uno {
  rotate: 45deg;
  transform: translate(2px, 2px);
  }
.visually-hidden {
  width            : 40px;
  height           : 40px;
  position         : absolute;
  right            : 6px;
  top              : 18px;
  background-color : #090c0f;
  opacity          : 0;
  z-index          : 4;
  }
#check:checked~#nav-list {
  display  : block;
  position : absolute;
  z-index  : 9;
  }
#nav-list li {
  float      : left;
  list-style : none;
  position   : relative;
  }
#nav-list li a {
  padding  : 0 20px;
  display  : block;
  position : relative;
  }
nav ul ul {
  display    : none;
  list-style : none;
  }
li:hover>ul {
  width      : fit-content;
  position   : absolute;
  display    : block;
  color      : #b98d69;
  transition : 0.75s;
  top        : 0;
  padding    : 35px 0;
  }
nav ul li a:hover {
  color      : #b98d69;
  transition : 0.75s;
  }
.sub-child li {
  background-color : #090c0f;
  width            : 200px;
  padding          : 5px 0;
  font-weight      : 300;
  }
.sub-child li a {
  padding-top    : 15px !important;
  padding-bottom : 15px !important;
  font-size      : 1.3rem;
  }


@media (min-width: 1000px)  /* Swiper Content Container till 1000px*/
  {
  #hamcross {
    display : none;
    }
  #check {
    display : none;
    }
  }

@media (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 100px) /* Swiper Content Container below 1000px*/
  {
  .book-a-table {
    display : none;
  }
  .uno,.duo {
    position         : absolute;
    height           : 2px;
    right            : 15px;
    top              : 35px;
    width            : 25px;
    background-color : aliceblue;
    transition       : all 1s;
  }
  .duo {
    top: 45px;
  }
  #check:checked~.duo {
    rotate: -45deg;
    transform : translate(5px, -5px);
  }
  #check:checked~.uno {
    rotate: 45deg;
    transform : translate(2px, 2px);
  }
  .visually-hidden {
    width            : 40px;
    height           : 40px;
    position         : absolute;
    right            : 6px;
    top              : 18px;
    background-color : #090c0f;
    opacity          : 0;
    z-index          : 4;
  }
  #nav-list {
    display : none;
  }
  #check:checked~#nav-list {
    display : block;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css"  />

<nav>
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul id="nav-list">
      <li>
        <a href="#">HOME:-<i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down ficont"></i></a>
        <ul class="sub-child">
          <li><a href="#">COFFEE HOUSE</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">RESTAURANT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">MENU:-<i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down ficont"></i></a>
        <ul class="sub-child">
          <li><a href="#">MENU COFFEE</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">MENU RESTAURANT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">PAGES:-<i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down ficont"></i></a>
        <ul class="sub-child">
          <li><a href="#">SERVICE</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">RESERVATION</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">HISTORY</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">OUR CHEFS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">FAQS</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">BLOG:-<i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down ficont"></i></a>
        <ul class="sub-child">
          <li><a href="#">BLOG GRID</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">BLOG STANDARD</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">BLOG SINGLE</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACTS</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="hamcross">
      <input type="checkbox" id="check" class="visually-hidden" />

      <div class="uno"></div>
      <div class="duo"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Pardon the long blocks of inefficient code. I am still learning, and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap for this?

Comment: Why are you complicating yourself? I suggested using Javascript and got the solution in 1 minute. I can send you the code if you want

Answer (score 0):

The reason your nav is not showing up is nav-list is a sibling to hamcross, hamcross is a parent to checkbox, uno and duo. Which means nav-list is like an uncle to checkbox, that is why #check:checked ~ #nav-list does not work. You need to have a hierarchy that you can traverse the dom with.
Check out this [link](https://alvarotrigo.com/blog/hamburger-menu-css/) for 10 examples css only!